# Make a new dataset from from average of subsets of another data set with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set (CSV file) with monthly benzine prices in Norway from 1986 to 2022. I want to make a new data frame with an average benzine price per year.
Furthermore, I managed to do it, but is there a more efficient way to do it? A link to the CSV file is given.
Here is what I did,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
bensin=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/.../BensinPris.csv",sep=',', delimiter=';')
bensinC=bensin.copy()
#Replace comma with dot in bensin price
bensinC.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','.'))
bensinC= bensinC.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
#Convert prices to floats from strings
bensinC['Priser (kr per liter)']=[float(x) for x in bensinC['Priser (kr per liter)']]
# Make a list of average bensin price each year

average=[]
yrs=np.arange(1986,2023,dtype='int')
for i in yrs:
    av=bensinC[[x[0:4]==str(i) for x in bensinC['ÅrMåned']]]['Priser (kr per liter)'].mean()
    average.append(np.round(av,2))
# Make a data frame for average bensin price
zipped = list(zip(yrs,average))
benisin_average=pd.DataFrame(zipped,columns=['Year','Average bensin price'])
benisin_average
# ploting
X=benisin_average['Year']
y=benisin_average['Average bensin price']
plt.plot(X[:],y[:])
plt.xlabel('Time(Year)')
plt.ylabel('Average bensin price (Norwegian krone/Liter)')
plt.show()
```

[Bensin Price](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApwAXA3k27sI1WVeW7hi6TfedE1Z?e=0B8hPp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I renamed your columns to `period` and `price` respectively. It's a little easier to understand for those who don't speak Norwegian.*

```py
# Modify the period column to an actual datetime
df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df.period.str.replace('M','',regex=False) + '01', 
                              yearfirst=True)
# Convert the price to a float
df['price'] = df.price.str.replace(',','.').astype('float')
# Resample the dataframe to end of year, apply the mean as aggregate
df_agg = df.resample('Y', on='period').mean().round(2).reset_index()
```

Resulting `df_agg` (sample):

| period | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1986-12-31 | 4.43 |
| 1987-12-31 | 4.65 |
| 1988-12-31 | 4.79 |
| 1989-12-31 | 5.13 |
| 1990-12-31 | 5.56 |
| 1991-12-31 | 6.4 |
| 1992-12-31 | 6.76 |
| 1993-12-31 | 7.12 |
| 1994-12-31 | 7.19 |

Note: [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample) allows you to use *[frequency strings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)*, which makes it possible to not only group by year, as we did in this example, but also e.g. by quater.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but the output of df_agg is just a data frame with only one column. I want a new data frame, and I need to change columns names to Period and average benzene price and then plot. For plotting, I just need the years and not days and months.

Comment: I added `reset_index()`. The period was in the index, by resetting the index, it becomes a column again.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_excel('BensinPris.xlsx')
df_avg = (
    df.groupby(df['ÅrMåned'].str[:4].astype(int))['Priser (kr per liter)'].mean()
      .round(2).rename_axis('Year').rename('Average bensin price').reset_index()
)
print(df_avg)

# Output
    Year  Average bensin price
0   1986                  4.43
1   1987                  4.65
2   1988                  4.79
3   1989                  5.13
4   1990                  5.56
5   1991                  6.40
...
31  2017                 14.64
32  2018                 15.55
33  2019                 15.69
34  2020                 14.69
35  2021                 16.52
36  2022                 18.64
```

Plot:

```
df_avg.plot(x='Year', y='Average bensin price')
```

[image]